# Kiel oni diras "Netbook" per Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi tradukis ĝin kiel "Retkomputilo," sed mi volas duan opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Ofta traduko estas *[tekokomputilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekokomputilo)* sed vi ankaŭ povus nomi tion per la pli ampleksa *[portebla komputilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portebla_komputilo)*.

Comment: "Tekokomputilo" estas por ordinara "**note**book" aŭ "laptop computer". ["**Net**book"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netbook) estas pli malgranda, pli malpeza, pli malkosta kaj pli malforta tia komputilo ol kutima "**note**book" aŭ "laptop computer".

Comment: @das-g, ne estas tiel klaraj difinoj, do _tekokomputilo_ kiel ĝenerala termino estas bona. Se vi nepre bezonas precizigi, diru ekz. "malgranda tekokomputilo", "tekokomputileto".